# Insert on duplicate key update is slower then select&insert?

Tags: mysql

When there are lots of duplicate keys in table, 'Insert on duplicate key update' is slower then 'select&insert'?

```sql
create table names
(
    id         bigint unsigned auto_increment,
    `name`     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    primary key (id),
    constraint uniq_name unique (`name`),
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

on duplicate update:

```sql
INSERT INTO names (`name`) VALUES ('name1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=`id`;
```

select insert:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) WHERE `name`='name';
```

when count is zero:

```sql
INSERT INTO names (`name`) VALUES ('name1');
```

Comment: Why would you update the ID if the name is already in the table?

Comment: 'UPDATE id = id' means ignoring updates

Comment: If you want to ignore insert if key already exists, you should use __INSERT IGNORE__. Select & update is slower than insert .. on update

Answer (score 1):

90% of a *simple* query is overhead -- sending across network, parsing, optimizing, locating the part of the table that might contain `name = 'name'`, gathering results (such as "count"), shipping the results (at least success/fail) back, etc.  Two queries means doing each of those twice.

Furthermore, the `COUNT` may be more costly than necessary.  If you didn't not have an `INDEX` starting with `name`, it will have to read the entire table.

And, if there are many rows with `name = 'name'`, `COUNT` will tell you how many there are, when all you needed to know was whether there were *any*.

You do have `UNIQUE name`.  In this case, `INSERT IGNORE` is a clear winner.

General rule:  fewer roundtrips to the server ==> faster.